# Source folder to IDE project (Netbeans, Eclipse, ...)

Tags: c, eclipse, netbeans, project

Maybe it's a simple question but I didn't succeed to solve it. DNSperf is a measurement tool from Nominum written in C. I wanted to do some changes on the code. So, I've downloaded the sources from their site. Now, I want to create a Netbeans project (or Eclipse if you want) from these sources. The source folder contains a lot of files (.h, .c, Makefile, .in files, ...) and I don't know how to do this. I used to import project that have been created by the same IDE but here I don't know if an IDE has been used, and if yes, which one.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution. I used Netbeans. You need to create a C/C++ project from existing sources in the New Project wizard. Then, you select the folder that contains sources files. If your source folder has a configure file, Netbeans will find it automatically, configure the project using it and it's done, you have a ready Netbeans project.

@OnurTurhan My source folder was intended to Red Hat Linux so I didn't need to use Cygwin, but thanks for your explanation. I think it's what Netbeans has done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

1) Download and install cygwin,

2) Download and extract eclipse-cdt,

3) Start eclipse,

4) Create empty c project selecting with cygwin-c toolchain (if you could not see cygwin toolchain there should be adding PATH variables kind of thing)

5) Copy your source codes to this project and create make targets below 
in the folder which has makefile in it;

configure

all

Firstly run configure, than all.

There could be some mistakes in steps, i do not try for your case.

Or simply after installing cygwin, from the cygwin console you can run

./configure

make all

in the folder which has makefile in it.